# Random Forest Regressor model in R?

Tags: python, r, random-forest

I'm currently using Python for Random Forest Regressor model:

```
rfr = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=42)

param_grid = {'bootstrap': [True],
 'max_depth': [10, 30, 50],
 'n_estimators': [200, 400, 600]}

CV = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = rfr, param_distributions = param_grid, n_iter = 5, cv = 5, verbose=2, random_state=42, n_jobs = -1)

CV.fit(x_train, y_train)

print('best model:', CV.best_params_,'\nbest score: %.2f' % CV.best_score_)
```

How do I re-code them in R? Especially for rfr, param_grid, and CV?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is going to be the `caret` package. This package doesn't really have models, it is like a framework. For example, when you train a `caret` model, the default model is from `randomForest::randomForest`.

**No encoding is needed or recommended.** I don't know of *any* models that require you to encode categorical data in R. However, it's always important to make sure the data types in your data are correct.

There is no instantiation using these methods.

Here are a few key functions you'll want to look at and why in the `caret` library.

- `createDataPartition`: splitting data; training/testing/validation (however you want)
- `train`: training a model
- `trainControl`: for setting whether you want to bootstrap, cross-validate, repeated cross-validate (and many more), how many times you want to do whatever it is you do, and how many times you repeat it.
- `modelLookup`: this is will tell you want controls you can put in place for the type of model you choose. For example, if you wanted to use `randomForest::randomForest`, `modelLookup` tells us that you can only grid `mtry`; if you used `ranger::ranger` (another library's random forest), `modelLookup` tells us you can grid `mtry`, `splitrule`, and `min.node.size`. (Both of these random forest models work for classification and regression.)

There's a great digital manual for `caret`, but it's a bit out of date (there are more models now, I believe; I think there are a few with different defaults, as well). [You can find that here.](https://topepo.github.io/caret/)

I'm going to use `ranger` in my example.
In a `ranger` model:

- `n_estimators` is equivalent to `num.trees`
- `max_depth` is equivalent to `max.depth`

Additionally, all of the arguments that are shown in help for `?ranger::ranger` can be added to `train()`, when the method is set to `ranger`.

> You don't need to call the library `ranger` when you run this code, but you do have to have the package installed.

Starting with some data and data prep (arbitrarily selected).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(caret)

data("midwest")

midwest <- midwest[, c(3:6, 17:20, 27)] %>% 
  mutate(state = factor(state), inmetro = factor(inmetro))
```

Now, I'm going to split the data to separate a validation set at 70/30.

```
# by setting a char/factor field, it's automatically stratified
set.seed(35)
tr <- createDataPartition(midwest$state, p = .7, list = F)
```

I'm going to show you how you might use `modelLookup` to find the model you want to use. For example, if you wanted to look at what models used a parameter that contains the word 'depth'. (Models can be decision tree-based, neural networks, or any other kind of model out there; it's never safe to assume!)

```
modelLookup() %>% 
  filter(str_detect(parameter, "depth"))
#          model         parameter              label forReg forClass probModel
# 1          ada          maxdepth     Max Tree Depth  FALSE     TRUE      TRUE
# 2       AdaBag          maxdepth     Max Tree Depth  FALSE     TRUE      TRUE
# 3  AdaBoost.M1          maxdepth     Max Tree Depth  FALSE     TRUE      TRUE
# 4   blackboost          maxdepth     Max Tree Depth   TRUE     TRUE      TRUE
# 5      bstTree          maxdepth     Max Tree Depth   TRUE     TRUE     FALSE
# 6       ctree2          maxdepth     Max Tree Depth   TRUE     TRUE      TRUE
# 7    deepboost        tree_depth         Tree Depth  FALSE     TRUE     FALSE
# 8          gbm interaction.depth     Max Tree Depth   TRUE     TRUE      TRUE
# 9      gbm_h2o         max_depth     Max Tree Depth   TRUE     TRUE      TRUE
# 10         pre          maxdepth     Max Tree Depth   TRUE     TRUE      TRUE
# 11      rFerns             depth         Fern Depth  FALSE     TRUE     FALSE
# 12     rfRules          maxdepth Maximum Rule Depth   TRUE     TRUE     FALSE
# 13      rpart2          maxdepth     Max Tree Depth   TRUE     TRUE      TRUE
# 14     xgbDART         max_depth     Max Tree Depth   TRUE     TRUE      TRUE
# 15     xgbTree         max_depth     Max Tree Depth   TRUE     TRUE      TRUE 

# forReg means for regression; forClass means for classification; prob means probability
```

As I stated, I'm going to use `ranger`.

```
modelLookup("ranger")
#    model     parameter                         label forReg forClass probModel
# 1 ranger          mtry #Randomly Selected Predictors   TRUE     TRUE      TRUE
# 2 ranger     splitrule                Splitting Rule   TRUE     TRUE      TRUE
# 3 ranger min.node.size             Minimal Node Size   TRUE     TRUE      TRUE
```

Using this information I can create my tuning grid.

```
tG <- expand.grid(mtry = c(3, 4, 6),                       # variables to split
                  splitrule = c("extratrees", "variance"), # model training btw splits
                  min.node.size = c(3, 5, 7))              # min qty obs at each node
```

I'm going to set up repeated cross-validation.

```
# establish how to train
tC <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", repeats = 5)
```

It's time to train the model. I want to point out that the manner in which I document arguments in `train` is partially related to what is documented for the `train` function, but the arguments

```
# using formula (that's tilde period comma to say 'and everything else')
set.seed(35)
fit <- train(poptotal~.,  
             data = midwest[tr, ], tuneGrid = tG, trControl = tC,
             method = "ranger", importance = "permutation", 
             scale.permutation.importance = T)
# Random Forest 
# 
# 309 samples
#   8 predictor
# 
# No pre-processing
# Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 5 times) 
# Summary of sample sizes: 281, 278, 277, 277, 277, 278, ... 
# Resampling results across tuning parameters:
# 
#   mtry  splitrule   min.node.size  RMSE       Rsquared   MAE     
#   3     extratrees  3               97994.57  0.9540533  23562.39
#   3     extratrees  5               99066.61  0.9523176  24111.05
#   3     extratrees  7               99757.54  0.9495842  24535.54
#   3     variance    3              114908.64  0.8855597  28326.62
#   3     variance    5              116839.06  0.8762747  28883.57
#   3     variance    7              116378.17  0.8766985  29118.59
#   4     extratrees  3               92825.54  0.9693964  20950.30
#   4     extratrees  5               93879.65  0.9677459  21342.85
#   4     extratrees  7               94963.99  0.9653268  21856.72
#   4     variance    3              108533.52  0.9188248  25262.68
#   4     variance    5              111004.38  0.9047721  26059.75
#   4     variance    7              111046.46  0.9068934  26089.53
#   6     extratrees  3               89392.68  0.9779004  18832.46
#   6     extratrees  5               90215.15  0.9764424  19059.87
#   6     extratrees  7               91033.46  0.9753090  19408.73
#   6     variance    3              101022.50  0.9531625  21934.87
#   6     variance    5              100856.81  0.9541640  21965.35
#   6     variance    7              102664.47  0.9506119  22347.86
# 
# RMSE was used to select the optimal model using the smallest value.
# The final values used for the model were mtry = 6, splitrule = extratrees and min.node.size = 3.
```

I can queue the performance of this model without all the extra information, view how Ranger would have scored the results, and view the prediction on the validation set.

```
p.tr <- predict.train(fit)                   # collect predicted values
postResample(p.tr, midwest[tr, ]$poptotal)   # calculate metrics
#         RMSE     Rsquared          MAE 
# 9.928424e+04 9.710269e-01 7.736478e+03  

fit$finalModel # DRASTICALLY different; these metrics are based on OOB!

# validation data
p.ts <- predict(fit, midwest[-tr, ])        # collect predicted values
postResample(p.ts, midwest[-tr, ]$poptotal) # calculate metrics
#         RMSE     Rsquared          MAE 
# 5.844063e+04 9.528124e-01 1.561766e+04
```

---

---

#### ----  additional explanations  ----

Additional explanations surrounding the functions and how they relate to their Python equivalents.

##### `createDataPartitition` vs `train_test_split`

When `createDataPartition` is used as demonstrated in my example, it returns a list of row index values that you will keep for your training sample. It does not return four separate lists or vectors, just one. (Unlike `train_test_split`)

The arguments I used for `createDataPartion` were a vector of data, a partition percentage, and that I wanted a vector, not a list returned.

For the vector of data, it's easiest to use a column of the dataset. However, a vector with the same length as the number of rows in the entire dataset would do the same thing.

When I wrote `midwest[tr, ]`, I selected specific rows in the data set based on that output from `createDataPartition`.

In terms of your call: `test_inds = createDataPartition(y`<s>= 1:length(y)</s>`, p = 0.2, list = F)`(start with removing the unnecessary content).

Now if you have a data frame (which most models will *require*, there is no reason to split `X` and `Y` within the data frame. If you do, you cannot use `formula` as an argument. However, if you wanted to go through that extra work, you can. If you do, then instead of `formula`, you need the arguments `x` and `y`.

Using my example data from above, I could write

```
fitr <- train(x = midwest[tr, -3], y = midwest[tr, ]$poptotal, method = "ranger")
```

Using your example from your comment, using the same model from my example, you would write

```
fitr <- train(x = X_train, y = y_train, method = "ranger")
```

If you had a dataset, `df1` that looked like this:

```
#            y        x1        x2       x3
# 1  -1.395833 10.707157 5903.8725 0.500412
# 2  -1.955195 10.144033 1836.2500 0.501276
# 3  -2.174564 10.501878 4371.2319 0.499002
# 4   3.147530  8.838499 1783.0806 0.500391
# 5  -4.119006  7.927986 2463.0425 0.500571
# 6  -3.706576  7.608005  878.8885 0.500297
# 7  -0.525999 11.299934 3388.3888 0.497471
# 8  -0.517687 11.473103 5006.4363 0.497595
# 9   4.250880 10.151943 5366.0677 0.499125
# 10  1.530718 11.688670 3097.4672 0.500691
```

Using the partition from your code (where `p = .2`), set to `test_inds`, let's say it returned a vector with `c(1, 2, 4, 8)`

```
set.seed(34)
test_inds <- createDataPartition(df1$x1, p = .2, list = F)
```

Now when I use, `df1[-test_inds, ]` I'll get the rows removed

```
#            y        x1        x2       x3
# 3  -2.174564 10.501878 4371.2319 0.499002
# 5  -4.119006  7.927986 2463.0425 0.500571
# 6  -3.706576  7.608005  878.8885 0.500297
# 7  -0.525999 11.299934 3388.3888 0.497471
# 9   4.250880 10.151943 5366.0677 0.499125
# 10  1.530718 11.688670 3097.4672 0.500691
```

If I wanted to split it as you had, I could.

```
X_train <- df1[-test_inds, -1]
Y_train <- df1[-test_inds, 1]
```

Another way to create `Y_train`:

```
Y_train <- df1[-test_inds, ]$y # same as other Y_train, different way of coding
```

These `train` function calls are **identical**.

```
fit <- train(y~., data = df1[-test_inds, ]) 

fit1 <- train(y ~ . , data = df1[-test_inds, ])

fit2 <- train(y~., data = df1, subset = -test_inds)

fit3 <- train(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = df1[-test_inds, ]) 

fit4 <- train(x = df1[-test_inds, -1], y = df1[-test_inds, 1])

fit5 <- train(x = df1[ , -1], y = df1$y, subset = -test_inds)

fit6 <- train(x = df1[ , -1], y = df1[ , 1], subset = -test_inds)

fit7 <- train(x = X_train, y = Y_train)
```

If you wanted to test these, here's the code to recreate `df1`

```
df1 <- structure(list(
  y = c(-1.395833, -1.955195, -2.174564, 3.14753, -4.119006, 
        -3.706576, -0.525999, -0.517687, 4.25088, 1.530718), 
  x1 = c(10.707157, 10.144033, 10.501878, 8.838499, 7.927986, 
         7.608005, 11.299934, 11.473103, 10.151943, 11.68867), 
  x2 = c(5903.872547, 1836.24996, 4371.231904, 1783.080566, 2463.042469, 
         878.888451, 3388.388772, 5006.436295, 5366.067723, 3097.467151), 
  x3 = c(0.500412, 0.501276, 0.499002, 0.500391, 0.500571, 
         0.500297, 0.497471, 0.497595, 0.499125, 0.500691)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

When you test, you have to set the seed between each model. If you set the method to `ranger`, you can use the argument `seed` inside `train`.

For example:

```
fit <- train(y~., data = df1[-test_inds, ], method = "ranger", seed = 35)
```

or

```
set.seed(35)
fit <- train(y~., data = df1[-test_inds, ])
```

or

```
set.seed(35)
fit <- train(y~., data = df1[-test_inds, ]) 
set.seed(35)
fit1 <- train(y ~ . , data = df1[-test_inds, ])
set.seed(35)
fit2 <- train(y~., data = df1, subset = -test_inds)
set.seed(35)
fit3 <- train(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = df1[-test_inds, ]) 
set.seed(35)
fit4 <- train(x = df1[-test_inds, -1], y = df1[-test_inds, 1])
set.seed(35)
fit5 <- train(x = df1[ , -1], y = df1$y, subset = -test_inds)
set.seed(35)
fit6 <- train(x = df1[ , -1], y = df1[ , 1], subset = -test_inds)
set.seed(35)
fit7 <- train(x = X_train, y = Y_train)

fit$results
#   mtry     RMSE  Rsquared      MAE   RMSESD RsquaredSD    MAESD
# 1    2 3.637085 0.8258667 3.413510 1.326739  0.3020918 1.274708
# 2    3 3.730395 0.8297140 3.481763 1.378773  0.2605953 1.345170 

fit1$results
#   mtry     RMSE  Rsquared      MAE   RMSESD RsquaredSD    MAESD
# 1    2 3.637085 0.8258667 3.413510 1.326739  0.3020918 1.274708
# 2    3 3.730395 0.8297140 3.481763 1.378773  0.2605953 1.345170 

fit2$results
#   mtry     RMSE  Rsquared      MAE   RMSESD RsquaredSD    MAESD
# 1    2 3.637085 0.8258667 3.413510 1.326739  0.3020918 1.274708
# 2    3 3.730395 0.8297140 3.481763 1.378773  0.2605953 1.345170 

fit3$results
#   mtry     RMSE  Rsquared      MAE   RMSESD RsquaredSD    MAESD
# 1    2 3.637085 0.8258667 3.413510 1.326739  0.3020918 1.274708
# 2    3 3.730395 0.8297140 3.481763 1.378773  0.2605953 1.345170 

fit4$results
#   mtry     RMSE  Rsquared      MAE   RMSESD RsquaredSD    MAESD
# 1    2 3.637085 0.8258667 3.413510 1.326739  0.3020918 1.274708
# 2    3 3.730395 0.8297140 3.481763 1.378773  0.2605953 1.345170
```

If you don't use the argument `method`, the default is `method = "rf"` which is *not* the same as `method = "ranger"`, so they wouldn't be equivalent.

Comment: Thank you so much Kat, that's so helpful!! I have a followup question: when you train mode you used fit <- train(poptotal~.,  
             data = midwest[tr, ], tuneGrid = tG, trControl = tC,
             method = "ranger", importance = "permutation", 
             scale.permutation.importance = T)  What is poptotal here?

Comment: That's the independent variable—the y. After the tilde is the x or dependent variable(s). Sorry about that! I should have included that info.

Comment: No No worries! So poptotal is y, and data = midwest[tr, ] is X?

Comment: No, poptotal comes from `midwest[tr, ]`. The tilde, period or 'everything else' is the x.  (The remaining columns in `midwest[tr, ]`) In `poptotal~.` <- the x is the period

Comment: So Sorry I'm a little confused here. What I'm doing is                                     test_inds = createDataPartition(y = 1:length(y), p = 0.2, list = F)
X_test = X[test_inds, ]
X_train = X[-test_inds, ]
y_test = y[test_inds]
y_train = y[-test_inds]  so how should I refer to poptotal~. and data in this case?

Comment: Do you mind if we could set up a Zoom call? That would be so appreciated!!

Comment: I started writing out the explanation. I keep running out of space. I'm going to edit my answer to answer your question instead.

Comment: I didn't see that request for Zoom when I made my comment. We must have done it at about the same time. I don't want to put any PII on SO, is there a way to set up Zoom that doesn't give anything away on the forum? If so, sure!  I'm sure a 12-year-old with access to Google could probably recreate my life, but you know? Why not make it a little bit more challenging?

Comment: I just saw your explanation, that's so detailed and I'm really appreciated it!! I don't mind to put down my Zoom link here though. When are you available this week and what time zone you're at? (Preferably weekend maybe?)

Comment: By the way I have another question: should x and y be in the same dataset?